# Pull google analytics data to my own admin panel

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am making my own custom admin panel (python) and I want to display my Google analytic data in there, rather than having to log into my Google analytics's page separately to view it there.

Is there a way to do this? I could only find posts from 2010 that said it wasn't possible but I was hoping in two years something has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply google - "Google Analytics API".  I found this interesting library quickly:

http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Take a look at Google's doc here : 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/

In my experience, it is quite impossible to get something as powerfull and complete as their interface though. But if you only want a few quick stats, then it is just fine.